# Sitecore MVC Model.Item

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

I'm using MVC in Sitecore and added below code to get last updated date.

I fellow one of example for this code, they said that **Model.Item** is to track the field of context item as datasource. But, I don't clearly understand what **Model.Item** works for because if I remove the Model.Item object, the result is the same.

```
This page was last modified on: @Html.Sitecore().Field("__Updated", Model.Item, new { format = "dd/mm/yyyy" })
```

Additionally, is it possible to use webForms (.ascx) on the placeholders created by webPage (.cshtml)??
I have many sublayouts created by webforms and would like to use them in .cshtml layout. How  to use them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Model.Item == Context.Item?

As @Jim-Noellsch mentioned, if your code is running based on the current context item, then the default will be the same as the Model.Item. However, if you are building datasource-driven components or have altered the bound item on the model using a controller, you will want to use Model.Item to ensure you pull the item bound to the model, and not the context item.

## Web Forms inside MVC layout?

As for web forms inside an MVC layout, I do not believe that Sitecore supports this out of the box. You can view some customizations that have been done by others to do something similar ([MVC inside web forms](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2012/december/mvc-webforms.aspx)). Essentially, this comes down to customizing the pipelines to allow your incompatible components to be processed.

## Hybrid Sitecore solutions

You can also build a hybrid site with some pages in Web Forms and some in MVC, but this may require you to translate some of your components from one to the other. I recently wrote a post on hybrids here: http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/05/MVC-Web-Forms-Hybrid-Sitecore.aspx

For a hybrid approach, if you need to have similar functionality on both layout types, then yes, you will need 'duplicate' components (one sublayout, one rendering). This is completely acceptable. You already have different layouts and templates, this is just another layer. You may also have put some presentation business logic in your sublayouts. You may want to think about moving that to a ViewModel class and then using the same class in both your rendering and sublayout

## Using ViewModel

For your Model.Item, instead of using a standard Sitecore Item for your Model, you can specify a business object that will be the model object instead. I have a SlideShare on [converting WebForms sublayouts to MVC renderings](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/slideshows/Sitecore-MVC-renderings.aspx). Slide 6 shows a ViewModel implementation example, and Slide 8 shows using it in an MVC View. From here, you could probably use the same ViewModel behind your sublayout to centralize some of your logic.

Comment: If I use hybrid site with some pages in web forms and some in MVC, I have to create another rendering component which already created from sublayout component. The component's functionality will be the same, but tech is different. Do you think it is okay?? All new pages will use MVC, but later I might have to translate web-form versions to MVC.

Comment: For a hybrid approach, if you need to have similar functionality on both layout types, then yes, you will need 'duplicate' components (one sublayout, one rendering). This is completely acceptable. You already have different layouts and templates, this is just another layer.

You may also have put some presentation business logic in your sublayouts. You may want to think about moving that to a ViewModel class and then using the same class in both your rendering and sublayout.

Comment: "moving that to a ViewModel class" means that "calling sublayout assembly in ViewModel and call define object or method in .cshtml"???? is it?? Could you give me any example??

Comment: Also, is it possible to use ViewWebPage to call existing .ascx on View page in MVC??

Comment: I'm not certain as to the use of ViewWebPage.
As for ViewModel, instead of using a standard Sitecore Item for your Model, you can specify a business object that will be the model object instead. I have a SlideShare on converting WebForms sublayouts to MVC renderings. Slide 6 shows a ViewModel implementation example, and Slide 8 shows using it in an MVC View. From here, you could probably use the same ViewModel behind your sublayout to centralize some of your logic.

LINK: http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/slideshows/Sitecore-MVC-renderings.aspx

Comment: I have updated the answer to contain the details from the comments... some of it was getting too long for comment text.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Sitecore().Field` will use the current context item if you don't specify something. Most likely, your `Model.Item == Sitecore.Context.Item`.